# Is it possible to perform Sqlite sync via Azure Mobile Services completely within Xamarin Forms iOS PCL project

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

After spending two straight days chasing the answer, I have to fall back and just ask:

Is it possible to perform Sqlite sync via Azure Mobile Services completely within Xamarin Forms iOS PCL project?

Any examples I have looked at (including those that claim that their emphasis is on PCL) all end up instantiating the MobileServicesClient within the Native iOS part of the solution, as well as performing the Sqlite sync via Azure Mobile Services within the native project as well.

My goal is to have a Xamarin.Forms solution, which relies on a Sqlite / Azure Mobile Services sync for all of its data and its offline needs. Such solution would not have to have any additional platform specific code, beside what is generated by the project template.
Furthermore, I intent on using Syncfusion Xamarin charts library, which only works within Xamarin.Forms project. The idea is to have Syncfusion chart source its data from the local Sqlite db, which, in turn, is periodically auto-refreshed using Azure Mobile Services Sqlite sync.
I think, that if I had to do all if the data sync business within my platform specific project, then I may not be able to use this Syncfusion Forms-only library.
Is it actually possible to do the Sqlite / Azure sync completely within the bounds of the PCL?

-Eugene

Comment: I've tried adding SQLite.cs to PCL project without success. I ended up using the Android (or iOS) part of my solution. I think the target profile of the PCL project does not support SQLite...

Comment: After a bit of digging: you can install SQLite.NET PCL nuget package  http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17300/project-pcl-and-nuget

Comment: Thanks Milen! I also kept looking, when I finally came across this great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYcM2DdZTmg , which was taken from Xamarin Evolve 2014 conference. The presented has a repo on his GitHub called FieldEngineerLite, which demonstrates Sqlite as well as the Azure Mobile Services sync of Sqlite - all within PCL. The only platform code there is 2 lines in AppSDelegate, having to do with Plaform Init.

Comment: This looks interesting, will take a look, thanks!

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-xamarin-ios-get-started-offline-data/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so.  Check out the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - particularly Chapter 3.  In addition, check out the underlying repo (link in the book) - there are several example setups of Xamarin Forms with Offline Sync in SQLite in there.  The Chapter3 sample is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use them with my project with removing Silverlight optins from my PCL project because of some System.Web methods are not available with it.

[image: PCL properties]

**On PCL:**

- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
- Newtonsoft.Json
- SQLite.Net
- SQLite.Net.Async

**On iOS Project:**

- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.1.0.0
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform
- Newtonsoft.Json
- SQLite.Net
- SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.Unified